# How to Get back stored data in LocalStorage HTML 5 in form of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

This Code works to Give me stored cars Name

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var carArray=[];
        function addToListCarArray(){
            var newCarName=document.getElementById('carName');
            carArray.push(newCarName.value);
            if(window.localStorage){
                localStorage.setItem("carNameKey",JSON.stringify(carArray));
            }

        }


        function readCarNames(){
            if(window.localStorage){
                var carNames=localStorage.getItem("carNameKey");
                carNames = JSON.parse(carNames);
                for (i=0;i<carNames.length;i++){
            alert(carNames[i]);
        }
            }
        }
    </script>
<title>Local Storage Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Demo of Local Strorage</h1>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="carName" name="carName"> </input>
    <button onclick="addToListCarArray()">Add Car</button>
    <button onclick="readCarNames()">Display</button>
    <p id="displayCarNames"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But how can i get the stored car names in form of an array and display it. I tried modifying the readCarNames() function in two ways but none of them worked.
I searched but everywhere it's all about passing the object and storing which i'm able to do but not able to retrieve it in form of an array and then print it

here is what i tried to work out but didn't worked (Edit: didn't worked out because of my Wrong Style of coding unfortunately)

```
function readCarNames(){
            if(window.localStorage){
                var carNames=localStorage.getItem("carNameKey");

                var resultCarNames[]=JSON.parse(carNames);
                resultCarNames.toString();
                document.getElementById("displayCarNames").innerHTML = resultCarNames;

            }
```

and the second one that i attempted but didn't worked .

```
function readCarNames(){
            if(window.localStorage){
                var carNames=localStorage.getItem("carNameKey");
                carNames = JSON.parse(carNames);
                var resultCarNames[];
                for (i=0;i<carNames.length;i++){
                resultCarNames.push(carNames[i]);
            }
            resultCarNames.toString();
            document.getElementById("displayCarNames").innerHTML = resultCarNames;
            }
```

---

EDIT: As pointed out the mistake i made by the veproza in Answer I was able to solve this ..

**Here is the working snippet**

```
function readCarNames(){
            if(window.localStorage){
                var carNames=localStorage.getItem("carNameKey");
                var resultCarNames=JSON.parse(carNames);
                document.getElementById("displayCarNames").innerHTML = resultCarNames;
                }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to display a string representation of array (which is JSON) you have to output the result of `getItem` as is.

Comment: you mean like this `function readCarNames(){
   if(window.localStorage){
    var carNames=localStorage.getItem("carNameKey");
    document.getElementById("displayCarNames").innerHTML = carNames;}` .. I'm getting it in String form ["name1", "name2","name3"]; but i wanted it to display in proper format of array like toString method does on array in javaScript .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet, you seem to have it working correctly. By the line

```
carNames = JSON.parse(carNames);
```

you have the array of strings in `carNames` variable. After all, you iterate on it in the following `for` loop. You can try it by adding a line printing it, e.g.

```
alert(carNames);
```

If you want to print it to an element, you may want something like this:

```
document.getElementById('displayCarNames').innerHTML = carNames;
```

So your basic *print array variable to an element* would look like this:

```
function readCarNames(){
    var storedString = localStorage.getItem("carNameKey");
    var parsedArray = JSON.parse(storedString);
    alert(parsedArray);
    document.getElementById('displayCarNames').innerHTML = parsedArray;
}
```

Now, why it doesn't work in your code: In your second and third snippets, you need to know that in JavaScript, you don't initialize an array variable with `var arr[]`. You just say `var arr = []` or `var arr = JSON.parse(string)`. So this

```
var resultCarNames[]=JSON.parse(carNames);
```

should actually be just

```
var resultCarNames=JSON.parse(carNames);
```

and then it'll work.

Also note that `variable.toString()` returns a new variable, but does not change the original variable. Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a.toString();
console.log(a); // [1, 2, 3] - an array
console.log(b); // "1,2,3" - a string
```

So in your code, the line `resultCarNames.toString();` doesn't do anything at all. Still, when assigning a variable to a DOM node via `.innerHTML`, it gets converted to `String` automatically.

The third snippet contains the same mistake with improper initialization. This time, the line `var resultCarNames[];` should be `var resultCarNames = [];`. Other than that, you have a bit of a mess with curly braces, as you're missing the one closing the `for` cycle.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing every mistakes that i made so clearly ... and cleanly  telling what wrong with my style of coding in javaScript :).. 
(regarding curly braces i missed curly braces while pasting here somehow .. other wise i take proper care of that )